# Android - ProgressBar updates once, but not twice

Tags: android, service, progress-bar, progress

** **SOLVED** ** *(see comments)*

I'm updating a `ProgressBar` (declared in the Activity's XML layout) through a `Service` running and notifying my `Activity`. Everything works fine in a first place when the Activity is first called. Then the Activity is finished through the finish() method, and the application continues to live its cycle.

Eventually this Activity is called again to perform the same operation. Problem is that the ProgressBar won't show any progress ! I compared the ProgressBar's vars on both instances of the Activity, exactly the same. I don't get it, really. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**MyActivity**

```
ProgressBar progressBar;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
     progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
     progressBar.setMax(100);
     progressBar.setProgress(0);
     ...
}

public void get_info_from_service(...) {
    progressBar.setProgress(service.getPercent()); 
}

void quit_activity{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), OtherActivity.class);
    MyActivity.this.finish();
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

---

**MyService**

```
for (Listener listener : listeners) {
    listener.send_notification(this);
}

public int getPercent(){
    return this.percent;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception? If yes then please post the log...

Comment: I edited the first post, but that won't help you. The Activity is correctly notified (hence the successful first instance) - the only possible problem in the Service would be a bad value of the percentage.

Comment: And this was it ! Damnit I spent so much time searching around the ProgressBar when the problem was on updating the percentage value. Grrrrr. Thanks for trying, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @greg Welcome to StackOverflow. In case you solve a question on your own, like this one, it's [perfectly ok to post an answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and accept it. You even get a shiny badge if you get some upvotes on the answer. ;) This helps in various ways *(e.g. keeps the "Unanswered" tab clean)*. Thanks.

Comment: "Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking." But will do !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Always make sure you reinitiate your variables before entering the algorithm again !